# Why doesn't internal CSS for mobile work in gmail?

Tags: html, css, google-schemas

I am sending an email from a php file to a gmail account.
The code i have is basic HTML and CSS.
The email looks fine on desktop, it has all of the styles, but in mobile (both the app and browser) the styles do not appear, it seems the internal CSS is being removed.

I even tried googles sample code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .colored {
        color: blue;
      }
      #body {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
        .colored {
          color:red;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='body'>
      <p>Hi Pierce,</p>
      <p class='colored'>
        This text is blue if the window width is
        below 500px and red otherwise.
      </p>
      <p>Jerry</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

These are my headers that are sent:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Optimization Manager <server07@host.secure-serve3.com>" . "\r\n" .
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

But even this doesnt work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Gmail strips almost everything. Also inline styles are preferable in email templates. More info at: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2016/10/gmail-update-googles-rendering-refresh/

Comment: maybe i read it wrong, but in the link you sent arent they basically saying that you can have internal CSS and that they now strip much less than before?

Comment: this is where i got the code from, they themselves say that its possible to do this and even give the example, it just doesn't seem to be working for me https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css

Comment: What's the device you are testing the mobile version on?

Comment: multiple, on an iphone (gmail app), android (gmail app), and desktop mobile version of gmail

Comment: Inline css always using for email template.In some case mail template not  working in few email provider  like outlook,yahoo mail etc

Answer (score -1):

Apply this may be it works, because my system it work fine and also clear cache, if still issues coming then let me know

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>sdb</title>
  <style>
    .colored {
      color: red;
    }
    
    #body {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      .colored {
        color: blue;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id='body'>
    <p>Hi Pierce,</p>
    <p class='colored'>
      This text is blue if the window width is below 500px and red otherwise.
    </p>
    <p>Jerry</p>
  </div>

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but that didn't help, i cleared the cache and added your code, still no styles in mobile though